# Diagnose slow wake up from sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power-management

My new work computer (Dell Precision T3600, 16GB RAM, SSD) running Windows 7 takes roughly 40 seconds to wake up from sleep mode.

How can I diagnose what's taking so long? And what can I do to reduce the time?

Comment: Do you have 3G modem there?

Answer (score 3):

You should install the [Windows Performance Toolkit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx) run [xbootmgr to see why Windows is slow to resume from sleep](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140247). Generate the XML, and look at the resume nodes. if you're unsure, upload the ETL file, I'll take a look at it.